# Get parsed or formatted value in react-admin field validation

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

this is my validation:

```
const validateMutation = [required(), number(), minValue(1)];
```

and this is my field:

```
<NumberInput
   variant="outlined"
   source={mutation}
   label="Amount"
   fullWidth
   isRequired
   validate={validateMutation}
   format={(v) => {
     if (v === "") return "";
     if (v === undefined) return undefined;
        return v * -1;
     }}
   parse={(v) => {
     if (v === "") return "";
        return v * -1;
     }}
 />
```

basically I got `mutation` in negative value from api, and I transform it into positive value to be shown in field and to be submitted in positive value as well, but the problem is when I submit the form it failed, the error below the mutation field says:

> Must be at least 1

It seems that this validation `minValue(1)` still hold negative value from api, How to make this validation `minValue(1)` receive parsed or formatted value which is already in positive value?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the validation checks are applied to the parsed value.

If you want to perform the checks on the formatted value instead, you need to re-apply the `format` function to the value before validating it, e.g.:

```
const applyFormat = (format, validator) => (value) => validator(format(value));
const formatFn = (v) => {
    if (v === '') return '';
    if (v === undefined) return undefined;
    return v * -1;
  };
const validateMutation = [
  required(),
  number(),
  applyFormat(formatFn, minValue(1)),
];
```

Comment: amazing thanks I'll try it. another one: honestly I still confuse the different between format and parse, can you explain? if I want to change value from api which one should I use? and if I want to change value before it sent to api which one should I  use?

Comment: This part of the react admin December update blog post may answer your questions: https://marmelab.com/blog/2022/12/08/react-admin-december-2022-update.html#better-support-for-empty-values-in-inputs